# How to update a column in BI publisher based on certain condition

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher

I am new in BI publisher. I want to update rtf template Amount column based on certain conditions. Suppose in Rtf template we have Amount field, the sign of amount field will change based on value of another column like 'DR/CR' column. So, if we have 'C' in 'DR/CR' column, then amount will be multiplied  by -1, else we keep the amount as it is. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Debo

Comment: Stack overflow is for improving code.  It is kind of bad form to supply no code with a question.  Even if it doesn't work you'd be well served to include some code you have tried instead of asking others to write it for you.

Comment: Well said, mate !

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a very beginner-level question, and is answered in both Oracle's documentation, and elsewhere online. Since there is no code posted, you could look at the default sample RTF templates provided by Oracle during installation. If BI Publisher is installed on your system, go down to the sample folder. On my system, this is at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\BI Publisher\BI Publisher Desktop\Template Builder for Word\samples\RTF templates
```

The advanced folder has more complex examples.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\BI Publisher\BI Publisher Desktop\Template Builder for Word\samples\RTF templates\Advanced
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the sign change to be visual:

```
<?if@inlines:DR/CR='C'?>-<?end if?><?AMOUNT?>
```

If you actually need the amount to be negated, because you intend to make calculations with the value, I think you'd have to change your query to conditionally negate the value. Another option would be to assign it to a variable and make your calculations on the variable.